# Nvidia 340.108 issues

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, restore

Last week I upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to version 18.04.05. Unfortunately it turned out, that after performing this update, NVIDIA Drivers 340.108 are not compatible anymore (I'm having GeForce 710M in my laptop) and I had to switch to open source driver Nouveau.

Is there some way to restore 340.108 version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't really upgrade to a point release of the same version. Point releases are just a way to consolidate updates so that people performing an initial install don't install very old software.  So your question seems to be predicated on a misunderstanding. How did you update your system?  Before this, how long had you waited since you updated last?  Hopefully you haven't actually neglected updates since April of 2018?  Did you get any errors during the upgrade?  Which packages were updated?

Comment: I see others with an 820m needed to use gdm instead of lightdm to let the 390 driver work.  Which are you using?

Comment: Hello, I was using gdm3.

Comment: Maybe the kernel switch in 18.04.5 messed things up.  Try uninstalling all the Nvidia packages, then install from the standard repos what's offered as "tested recommended" for the Software and Updates/Additional Drivers.

Comment: Hello, I finally handled with the problem. Reinstalled gdm3 and installed graphics drivers from this PPA (nvidia-390).

https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

now everything works well